# what is the Analyze and Optimize button do in degragment software in windows

Tags: windows-8.1, defragment

[image: Optimize Drivers software in windows]

what is the difference between `analyze` and `optimize` buttons in the disk optimize software in windows.

```
OS windows 8.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Optimize function is for SSDs and uses TRIM to Optimize. SSDs do not use defragmentation - Just HDDs.

**For SSDs**:

> A trim command ... allows an operating system to inform a solid-state
> drive (SSD) which blocks of data are no longer considered in use and
> can be wiped internally

The Analyze button does not apply to SSDs.  Analyze is to determine if a Hard Drive needs defragging.

Windows does a good job of automatically defragging hard drives so Defrag is not needed too frequently.

**HDD Defrag** (All the drives in the question are HDD):

> Disk defragmentation takes all the pieces of each file, and stores
> them in one place. It also makes sure programs are each in one place,
> and that unused space on the hard disk is all together.

This can increase disk efficiency

The screen shot is from Windows 10 but it is the same in Windows 8.

[image]

Comment: OP doesn't have any SSDs in his system, so this answer isn't really relevant. It might be worth giving a brief explanation of both TRIM and defrag and explaining that "optimize" is a "one-word-fits-all" and is thus why it's used here.

Comment: Yes, but I answered the question about Optimize and then in my answer noted about HDD defrag..  I added additional information as you suggested.